# Excel 2013 on W10: VBA Vlookup in a different worksheet produces error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm developing an application which uses specification codes to vlookup those codes in another spreadsheet, and return vendor numbers from the second spreadsheet to the first, listing them in the same column with the specification code.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(specsec, [Vendorspec.xlsx!vid], 4)
```

in the above code line:

- specsec is the specification code, of the form XX XX XX.XX
- The name of the vlookup target file is "VendorSpec.xlsx".  In this worksheet, each code is a unique entry in column 1, with the first of several vendor numbers in column 4.  Future code will cycle through the columns, returning all subsequent vendor IDs for the current code.

The code line produces error "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheet function class".

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Thank you.

Comment: your code works for me _provided_ `Vendorspec.xlsx` workbook is open _and_ `vid` is a valid workbook scoped named range in that workbook _and_ the value of `specsec` exists in the first column of range `vid` _and_ `vid` is at least four columns wide

Comment: Can you try without usind `.FormulaR1C1`, just with `ActiveCell = Application...`?

Comment: I don't think you can assign a function like that to FormulaR1C1 as it will calculate the WorksheetFunction and just push the result. If you want the formula to remain in the cell that you have to push the formula as a string. If you just want the results of the formula to stay in the cell than use `ActiveCell.Value2`.

Comment: @nbayly you _can_ do that assignment, but there is little point.  The end result of assigning a value (in this case the result of the vlookup) to `FormulaR1C1`, `Formula`, `Value`, or `Value2` is the same

Comment: I can never remember which one does it, but between `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` (early-bound) and `Application.VLookup` (late-bound, no intellisense), one will raise a runtime error when the VLOOKUP fails, and the other will *return an error value* instead. Also, if you intend to set the *value* of `ActiveCell`, then set its `.Value`. If you intend to give it a *formula*, assign its `.Formula` with a string that contains that formula. It's not clear from the code what your intent is.

Answer (score 1):

Your lookup is simply failing, and the error message is utterly misleading.

It's not that VBA couldn't find the `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` member, it's just that your VLookup raised an error.

You need to either:

- Handle that runtime error with an `On Error GoTo` statement

Or

- Use the late-bound version `Application.VLookup`, which doesn't give you *IntelliSense*, but instead of throwing a runtime error when the lookup fails, it will return "Error 2042" and you can test whether the lookup failed or not by wrapping it in `IsError`.

---

Type `42` in cell `A1` of the active sheet. Then in the *immediate pane*:

```
?iserror(application.VLookup(42,Range("A:B"),1,false))
```

returns `False`

```
?iserror(application.VLookup(43,Range("A:B"),1,false))
```

returns `True`

```
?application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(42,Range("A:B"),1,false)
```

returns `42`

```
?application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(43,Range("A:B"),1,false)
```

raises a runtime error:

[image: Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class]

That message would be better worded as "VLookup function failed to find specified lookup value in specified lookup range", or something like that.

---

The reason your lookup is failing is the same any VLOOKUP might fail for: verify your `lookup_value` actually exists in your `lookup_range`. Watch out for leading and/or trailing spaces, and "text-formatted" columns. In other words, assuming you *want* to throw a runtime error when the lookup fails, it's a data problem, not a code problem.