# Use Vlookup() With VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I keep getting an error of

> Object Required

running my syntax.  This is the syntax that I have, but it is not successful.  How can I write the `Vlookup()` value to my current worksheet cell T1?

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim dblInfo
  dblInfo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("A2", Sheet1.Range("A2:F171"), 4, False)
  Range("T1").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = dblInfo
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly which line is raising the "object required" error?

Comment: Note that you'll be facing yet another runtime error (1004) when the lookup fails, and you're not handling it. `dblInfo` should be declared with an explicit type (and no Hungarian prefix, please); `Dim whateverThisActuallyIs As Double`. If you mean `dblInfo` to contain an error value when the lookup fails, declare it `As Variant` and use the late-bound `Application.VLookup` function instead. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40877404/1188513) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to enter the VLookup formula into T1

```
Range("T1") = "=VLookup(A2, Sheetname!A2:F171, 4, False)"
```

Otherwise, if you want to calculate the VLookup and then just enter the result...

```
Range("T1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([A2], Sheetname.Range("A2:F171"), 4, False)
```

Comment: The top solution is giving me a #NAME? in cell T1 and the bottom gives me the same object required error

Comment: the A2:F171 is on a different sheet than Range("T1") - how do I qualify the sheet name?

Comment: @SmallFriesBigGuys Edited